# DDL Logs In Postgresql.Conf File

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I want to log only ddl commands to my postgresql .wal files. So, i configured my postgresql.conf file to log those sql queries but it did not work. It cathes every query that works on my postgresql server. How can i do it? I just want to log only ddl commands.

Comment: "So, i configured my postgresql.conf file to log those sql queries but it did not work."  How?  What did you actually do?

Comment: There are no ".wal" files.  There are WAL files, but their name does not end in ".wal".  And these are **not** the human readable log files.  The human readable logs end in ".log".

Comment: @jjanes I actually made the log_statement = 'ddl' in postgresql.conf file. Was it worng? It did not work.. I just want postgresql to log only ddl commands.

Comment: That is probably the correct thing to do. Did you "reload" or "restart" the server afterwards, so that it picked up the change? Did you remove the "#" from the front of the line?  And, what did you change it from? Was it previously set to 'all'?There are other reasons it might log the statements, such as auto_explain or log_min_duration_statement.  Also, log_statement can be overridden per user or per database, and those settings are stored in the database itself and so won't show up in the *.conf file.  You can log in and do `show log_statement` to see what is currently in effect.

Comment: Yes, i have removed # sign from the front line and restarted the pgservice. But, still same thing goes on. I will try to do thing that you mention last sentences. If they doesn't work again, i will give information in here. Thank you so much.